# my local host name does not pair with 127.0.0.1 on mac

Tags: python, macos, server

I used this command line "sudo scutil --set HostName " to set my hostname on mac.But when I do serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 16027)). It always shows error "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXNB9.png). I did a lot of search but none of them helped. Could anyone help me solve this? Thanks so much

Comment: The name <--> address translation is not a trivial topc. Anyway, you probably don't have to bother now, because network servers usually simply listen on all interfaces (IPv4 address 0.0.0.0) unless they are configured otherwise. And when they are manually configured, addresses (not names) are preferred.

Comment: What is the output of  `hostname` command? You can also set name using it. `hostname myserver`